# Selecting a subset of integers given two lists of end points

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, zip, concatenation

I have two lists of end points that look like this:

```
t1 = [0,13,22]
t2 = [4,14,25]
```

I am looking for the most efficient way to generate an output that looks like this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,13,14,22,23,24,25]
```

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested list commprehension:

```
[i for a, b in zip(t1, t2) for i in range(a, b + 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @blhsing, I really appreciate it. I wonder if there is a numpy equivalent of the solution though, because I heard the numpy version of anything code related is a lot faster

Comment: @mathguy "I heard the numpy version of anything code related is a lot faster": I'm afraid you heard wrong. Perhaps you meant "array / list related" when you say "code related", but even then. For such small lists as here, it will unlikely be (a lot) faster, and both variants would complete in such a short amount of time, you wouldn't even be able to blink your eyes in that timespan, making any speed-up insignificant.

Comment: @9769953 Thank you for your reply. This example is merely a scaled down problem with what I am working with. What I am working with involves two lists a couple of thousands long, and about millions of iterations. So anything that can improve the speed will be of help

Comment: @mathguy then you should provide the proper context/example code, because the actual issue may be in how you approach your problem. Sometimes, millions of iterations can be reduced to just a few (or none) with the right (NumPy / vectorized) approach.