# Numpy version of this particular list comprehension

Tags: python, list, performance, numpy, list-comprehension

So a few days ago I needed a particular list comprehension in this thread: [Selecting a subset of integers given two lists of end points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877743/selecting-a-subset-of-integers-given-two-lists-of-end-points)

and I got a satisfying answer. Fast forward now, I somehow need to boost the performance, as what I am working with involves looping it and in each iterations the lengths of these end-point arrays are at least few thousands.

So my question is is there any functions in numpy package that can get the job done but a lot faster? I've looked into numpy's linspace, repeat, arange and stuff, and couldn't find any breakthrough. And if there is a way to get the job done faster, can you guys show me the way?

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Please provide a standalone question, with self-contained example code and examples for what you've already tried.

Comment: Ok I will ask again later with a better presentation. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: You can [edit] your question directly, which is better than asking again later.

Answer (score 2):

If it is still of interest to you, you could get rid of one `for` loop and use `numpy.arange()` in combination with list comprehension and `numpy.hstack()` to get what is desired. Having said that we would still need at least one `for` loop to get this done (because neither `range` nor `arange` accept a sequence of endpoints)

```
t1 = [0,13,22]
t2 = [4,14,25]
np.hstack([np.arange(r[0], r[1]+1)  for r in zip(t1, t2)])

# outputs
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 13, 14, 22, 23, 24, 25])
```

However, I don't know how much more performant this is going to be for your specific case.

Comment: Appreciate for the help, I will look into how much it has improved.

Comment: @mathguy sure, please let me know so that I can improve my answer, if possible :)

Comment: weird, in my pc the old solution is faster than the new one. the old one takes 13.4ms per loop and the new one takes 50.4ms per loop. the t1 adn t2 I am working with have 10,000 entries instead of 3 though