# How to create a 2D array of ranges using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of start and stop indices, like this:

```
    [[0, 3], [4, 7], [15, 18]]
```

and i would like to construct a 2D numpy array where each row is a range from the corresponding pair of start and stop indices, as follows:

```
    [[0, 1, 2],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [15, 16, 18]]
```

Currently, i am creating an empty array and filling it in a for loop:

```
    ranges = numpy.empty((3, 3))
    a = [[0, 3], [4, 7], [15, 18]]

    for i, r in enumerate(a):
        ranges[i] = numpy.arange(r[0], r[1])
```

Is there a more compact and (more importantly) faster way of doing this? possibly something that doesn't involve using a loop?

Comment: Just do `np.asarray(a)[:, :1] + np.arange(a[0][1] - a[0][0])`

Comment: Would the difference between start and stop across all pairs be the same?

Comment: @Divakar, yes, they would be the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use broadcast to add the left hand edges to the base arange:

```
In [11]: np.arange(3) + np.array([0, 4, 15])[:, None]
Out[11]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [15, 16, 17]])
```

Note: this requires all ranges to be the same length.

Comment: Awesome! thanks. @jdehesa's solution also works but this seems to run a bit faster

Answer (score 2):

If the ranges were to result in different lengths, for a vectorized approach you could use [`n_ranges`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55918555/9698684) from the linked solution:

```
a = np.array([[0, 3], [4, 7], [15, 18]])

n_ranges(a[:,0], a[:,1], return_flat=False)
# [array([0, 1, 2]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([15, 16, 17])]
```

---

Which would also work with the following array:

```
a = np.array([[0, 3], [4, 9], [15, 18]])
n_ranges(*a.T, return_flat=False)
# [array([0, 1, 2]), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), array([15, 16, 17])]
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete solution, but i forgot to make it clear in my question that the ranges would all be the same length.

Comment: @yatu I don't see the `return_flat`-variable in the linked code?