# using np.where with indices

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have an array of zeros (17520,5) that I want to fill with two values: 0 and 0.05. I have two conditions, and I am using the function np.where, however, I only need to apply the second condition at specific indices of the array. The code I am using is as follows:

```
independent = np.zeros([17520,5])
w1 = np.where(independent == 0)
independent[w1] = np.random.choice([0.0, 0.05], size=len(w1[0]))
```

This part of the code works fine, and fills the zero array (independent) with the desired values: 0 and 0.05 with the same proportion (50/50). On the other hand, the second condition needs to be implemented only at specific indices, something as follows:

```
for n in range(0, 365):
    start = 24 + n*48
    end = 46 + n*48
    w2 = np.where(independent == 0.05)
    independent[w2][start:end,0:5]=np.random.choice([0.0, 0.05], (22,5),size=len(w2[0]))
```

Where [start:end,0:5] indicates the indices where I want to implement the conditions w2.

I would appreciate your help indicating the correct way to use the function np.where with indices, because at the moment I am having the following error

```
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The problem is in `np.random.choice()`. Both `(22,5)` and `len(w2[0])` are inputs for the same variable `size`.

Comment: I left only (22,5) and Im having the following error IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: Now the problem is in `independent[w2][start:end,0:5]`. You are giving too many indices, in the second square bracket only one between `start:end` and `0:5` should be there. Or you have to remove the first square bracket.

Comment: independent[w2] is a copy, not a view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) can also take two *array_like* arguments from which to choose depending on the *condition*. Here's how you could use `np.where` in your case:

```
for n in range(0, 365):
    start = 24 + n*48
    end = 46 + n*48
    independent[start:end,0:5] = (np.where(independent== 0.05, 
                                          np.random.choice([0.0, 0.05], 
                                                    size=independent.shape), 
                                          independent)[start:end,0:5])
```

---

It's a little tricky but the above can be vectorized. The key is getting a list of ranges where we want `independent` to be updated. For that we can use [`n_ranges`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55918555/9698684) from the linked answer, which can be used to obtain a flat array with all ranges from the corresponding `start` and `end`:

```
start = 24 + np.arange(0, 365)*48
end = 46 + np.arange(0, 365)*48
ranges = n_ranges(start, end)
independent[ranges,0:5] = (np.where(independent== 0.05, 
                                   np.random.choice([0.0, 0.05], 
                                                    size=independent.shape), 
                                   independent)[ranges,0:5])
```

---

Checking the timings, we can see that with the second approach we gain over a **`260x`** speedup!

```
def vect_approach(a):
    start = 24 + np.arange(0, 365)*48
    end = 46 + np.arange(0, 365)*48
    ranges = n_ranges(start, end)
    a[ranges,0:5] = (np.where(a== 0.05, 
                             np.random.choice([0.0, 0.05], size=a.shape ),
                             a)[ranges,0:5])

def loopy_approach(x):
    for n in range(0, 365):
        start = 24 + n*48
        end = 46 + n*48
        independent[start:end,0:5] = (np.where(independent== 0.05, 
                                              np.random.choice([0.0, 0.05], 
                                                        size=independent.shape), 
                                              independent)[start:end,0:5])
```

---

```
independent = np.zeros([17520,5])

%timeit loopy_approach(independent)
# 475 ms ± 19.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit vect_approach(independent)
# 1.87 ms ± 95.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, the first solution works, however, when I try to use the second one, I've got the following error NameError: name 'n_ranges' is not defined

Comment: Yes @JonathanBudez go to the link I've attached, `n_ranges` is an answer of mine in some other post. Use that function. It'll speed up your implementation :)