# Vectorize index identification for faster GPU processing

Tags: optimization, pytorch, gpu

My input is a list of values, `data_idx`. In the example, the values range from [0, 5].

```
data_idx = [2, 5, 5, 0, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0]
```

My desired output, `filled_matrix` is a tensor of shape `max(value)` by `len(data_idx)` where each row, `r`, of the tensor contains all of indices where `data_idx == r` and -1 for the rest of the row if the number of matched indices is fewer than `len(data_idx)`

For example, in the first row, `r=0`, `data_idx==0` at indices `[3, 11, 14]`. The full output would look like:

```
filled_matrix = tensor([[ 3, 11, 14, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], 
    [ 5, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    [ 0,  9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    [ 8, 12, 13, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    [ 4,  6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    [ 1,  2,  7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]],
   dtype=torch.int8)
```

I have working for-loop code that accomplishes my goal.

```
import torch

max_idx = 6
data_idx = torch.tensor([2, 5, 5, 0, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0]).cuda()

max_number_data_idx = data_idx.shape[0]

filled_matrix = torch.zeros([max_idx, max_number_data_idx], dtype=torch.int8, device='cuda')
filled_matrix.fill_(-1)
for i in range(max_idx):
   same_idx = (data_idx == i).nonzero().flatten()
   filled_matrix[i][:same_idx.shape[0]] = same_idx
```

Now, I want to speed up this code. Specifically, I want it to be faster on the GPU. In the real scenario, the input, `data_idx`, can be a list containing millions of values. In that case, e.g 1 M of different values, the GPU will be call 1 M of time which make it very slow. My code is sequential and GPU hate sequential code.

Is there a function which will produce the same result more efficiently? Or a way to vectorize this for-loop?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what your goal is and what isn't working? For example, what is your desired output? What do you get instead?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, my output is the "filled matrix". I want to find a way to optimize this code on GPU and have the same output

Comment: So just to clarify, this code does what you want on the gpu and now you want to move it to the cpu?

Comment: It is working on both. I want to optimize it only for gpu. The code bellow is just an example. In the real scenario the input, data_idx, can be a list containing millions of values. In that case, e.g 1 M of different values, the gpu will be call 1 M of time which make it very slow. My code is sequential and gpu hate sequential code. So for me, the first option is either try to find a way to avoid the use of a loop (may be there is a hidden pytorch function that I do not know) or find a way to parallelize the loop. Thanks you again

Comment: based on your comments, I tried to re-write your question to be a little clearer. Hopefully, this will help you get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Disclaimer: I have not profiled this code too see if it is actually faster on a GPU.***

One vectorized solution is to use tensor views to broadcast the comparison. Tensor views do not use additional memory. You can see more details in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_view.html)

First, make a matrix that contains the values that you want to compare to for each row. In this case, it's just the row indices.

```
comparison = torch.tensor(range(max_idx))
```

Now we are going to use [`expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand) and [`unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.unsqueeze) to make views of `data_idx` and `comparison` which are the same shape as `filled_matrix`.

```
comparison_view = comparison.unsqueeze(1).expand(max_idx, max_number_data_idx)
print(comparison_view)

# Each row is the index you want to compare to
# tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]])

data_idx_view = data_idx.expand(max_idx, max_number_data_idx)
print(data_idx_view)

# Each row is a copy of data_idx
# tensor([[2, 5, 5, 0, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0],
    [2, 5, 5, 0, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0],
    [2, 5, 5, 0, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0],
    [2, 5, 5, 0, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0],
    [2, 5, 5, 0, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0],
    [2, 5, 5, 0, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0]])
```

We can compare their equality and use [`nonzero`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.nonzero) to find the indices

```
mask = comparison_view == data_idx_view
mask_indices = mask.nonzero()

print(mask_indices)
# tensor([[ 0,  3],
    [ 0, 11],
    [ 0, 14],
    [ 1,  5],
    [ 1, 10],
    [ 2,  0],
    [ 2,  9],
    [ 3,  8],
    [ 3, 12],
    [ 3, 13],
    [ 4,  4],
    [ 4,  6],
    [ 5,  1],
    [ 5,  2],
    [ 5,  7]])
```

Now, you just need to manipulate these results into the format that you want for your output.

```
filled_matrix = torch.zeros([max_idx, max_number_data_idx], dtype=torch.int8)
filled_matrix.fill_(-1)
col_indices = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
filled_matrix[mask_indices[:, 0], col_indices] = mask_indices[:, 1].type(torch.int8)
```

I thought about several options for generating the `col_indices` list, but I couldn't come up with anything without a for loop.

```
col_indices = torch.zeros(mask_indices.shape[0])
for i in range(1, mask_indices.shape[0]):
    if mask_indices[i,0] == mask_indices[i-1,0]:
        col_indices[i] = col_indices[i-1]+1
```

You would need to do some profiling to see which code is actually faster.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thank you very much for your help, it works very well. I tried it on my real code and it is 3-4 times faster. For generating the col_indices I used something else, explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916932/multiple-ranges-np-arange  . Thank you again it really helps me a lot!